# How do I use this command in a pre build event in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, command, pre-build-event

I will be concise.

The command `FOR /F %i IN (C:\Version.txt) DO @set Version=%i` works perfectly fine in `cmd.exe` to read the text of the file into a variable. but whenever I put that line into a prebuild event in Visual Studio it says `Exited with code 255`.

On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx I found that 0xFF / 255 means: `The extended attributes are inconsistent.`.

How do I use that command in a pre build event?
Many thanks.

Comment: What is in version.txt? Just something like "1.0.0.0"? And what version of VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
FOR /F %%i IN (C:\Version.txt) DO @set Version=%%i
```

However this will not work as you epxect: VS spawns a cmd.exe process to execute build events, meaning that if you set a variable it is local to that cmd.exe only, hence the rest of your build will not have access to `Version`.

Luckily there are much better alternatives than batch files: if you're using VS2010 or higher, the project files are msbuild files, so to get all possible versioning things working you just create a common msbuild script to do whatever you need to do with the version (eg create a .res file if it's for C++, or modify the AssemblyInfo.cs for C#) and include it in all your projects.

Comment: The double `%%` did the trick. I can use the `Version` variable in the build event now. Many thanks.